# Is there a way to extract secret key from NSS

Tags: java, cryptography, fips, nss

I am using NSS as my keystore. I have generated a secret key which i use for encrypting/decrypting sensitive data (using AES) and all works fine.

For portability, is there a way in which this secret key can be extracted and inserted back to a different NSS DB?

I am using jre6 with SunPKCS11 provider. I am generating key as follows

```
KeyStore ks = //get NSS keystore
    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kg.init(128);
    SecretKey skey = kg.generateKey();
    ks.setEntry(SECREY_KEY, new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(skey), 
            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pw.toCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the NSS toolkit, it has [a utility](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/pk12util.html) to extract PKCS#12 keys from NSS keystores:

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/

Comment: pk12util seems to be useful only for public/private keys.

Comment: The only other thing I can come up with is talking to the library directly using the open source IAIK PKCS#11 wrapper library. As long shot you could try converting the key back to software using a JCE SecretKeyFactory.